# Getting Intent Chooser to work with a ACTION_DIAL Uri

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm having some trouble getting Intent Chooser to pop up when trying to start a Dial Intent.

```
Intent diallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL,(Uri.parse("tel:"+ result.international_phone_number)) );
String title = "Choose";
Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(diallIntent , title);

    if (callIntent.resolveActivity(getActivity().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(chooser);
    }
```

This code just starts the android built-in phone app, and does not show a chooser. If I set android:autoLink="phone" on the corresponding textview, not run this code, and set the text to the international_phone_number var, I do get Chooser pop-up (standard phone app or Skype), so that rules out any external settings or non-installed phone apps.

What am I doing wrong? Am I parsing the Uri wrongly? Is ACTION_DIAL intent not compatible with Skype?

Thanks in advance for any possible answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Linkify](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html), which powers `android:autoLink` uses [URLSpan](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/URLSpan.html) which, per [the source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/style/URLSpan.java), uses `Intent.ACTION_VIEW` Intents along with the URI. Skype only appears to support `ACTION_VIEW` and not `ACTION_DIAL`.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's why I am a n00b, and you have 12.2k points :)